# Cant access the variable as variable stored in a file using bash

Tags: bash, file, shell, git-bash

I have a bash script like

```
source ./testscript

while read line
do
      echo "$line"
done < "test.file"
```

where the testscript is like

```
VAR="hello"
```

the test.file is like

```
"$VAR" world!!!
```

I expect the output of my bash script to be

> hello world!!!

but what i get is

> "$VAR" world!!!

Is there any solution?

Comment: Why do you want/need this? What are you trying to solve with your script?

Comment: Are variables in `test.file` always quoted?

Answer (score 1):

you can try

```
echo `eval "echo $line"`
```

instead of

```
echo "$line"
```

Comment: Didn't downvote but yeah, most certainly because of that. You just don't `eval` a complete file to only get parameter expansion working.

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth Very true, just don't see what a downvote helps. Something of this sort is the answer to the question, could use a disclaimer though.

Comment: @BroSlow Not really, `eval` is (almost) always an incorrect answer and there's (almost) always a better approach to solve the problem. To quote someone else: *"In the majority of cases, eval is used like a sledgehammer swatting a fly -- it gets the job done, but with too much power."*. This is especially true in this very case.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to use `eval`. `eval` would allow arbitrary code to be embedded into your (text?) file which is certainly not what you want, especially if untrusted users have write access to said file.

If you don't need to expand arbitrarily named variables you can do something like the following, but there might be a better approach to the problem you are actually trying to solve.

```
$ cat t.sh
#!/bin/bash

VAR1=hello
VAR2='!!!'
FOO=test

expand_vars()
{
        local s=$*
        local var
        for var in VAR{1..9} FOO; do
                s=${s//%${var}%/${!var}}
        done
        echo "${s}"
}

while read line; do
        line=$(expand_vars "${line}")
        echo "${line}"
done <<__DATA__
%VAR1% world%VAR2%
This is a %FOO%
__DATA__
```

.

```
$ ./t.sh
hello world!!!
This is a test
```